# TypeError: context must be a dict rather than HttpResponseRedirect: Is it really impossible to redirect to a url without using test_func()?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to make it such that if the user has blocked me or if I have blocked the user, I want to redirect them back to the homepage and not allow them to view the detail page. Because this is a class based view, do you have any ways for me to achieve what I want and not affecting what already exists?

I tried to do all sorts of things but didn't work, and none of my friends could solve this. I cannot directly use return redirect(HomeFeed:main) because I have other contexts in the same view which I need it to return in the template.

I also do not want to use UserMixin's test_funct() which involves showing a 403 Forbidden Error because it isn’t user friendly and doesn’t show the user what exactly is happening. That’s why I want to do a redirect followed by django messages to inform them why they can’t view the page

```
class DetailBlogPostView(BlogPostMixin,DetailView):
    template_name = 'HomeFeed/detail_blog.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        blog_post=self.get_object()
        blog_post.save()
        context['blog_post'] = blog_post
        account = Account.objects.all()
        context['account'] = account
        if blog_post.interest_set.exists():
            context["interest_pk"]=blog_post.interest_set.first().pk
        
        if blog_post.author in self.request.user.blocked_users.all():
            messages.warning(self.request, 'You cannot view post of ideas authors that you have blocked.', extra_tags='blockedposts')
            hi = redirect('HomeFeed:main')
            context['hi'] = hi
        if blog_post.author in self.request.user.blocked_users.all():
            messages.warning(self.request, 'You cannot view post of ideas authors that have blocked you.', extra_tags='blockeduposts')
            hi = redirect('HomeFeed:main')
            context['bye'] = bye
        return context
```

Comment: Please edit title for it to be descriptive,  "Difficult Django" and "urgent" are not something that should be in title of the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in get [method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2b4b6c8af0aae8785bc1347cf1be2e8e70fd5ff3/django/views/generic/detail.py#L103):

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = blog_post = self.get_object()
        blog_post.save()
        if blog_post.author in request.user.blocked_users.all():
            messages.warning(request, 'You cannot view post of ideas authors that you have blocked.', extra_tags='blockedposts')
            return redirect('HomeFeed:main')
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
    ...
```

---

UPDATE

YOUR VIEW:

```
class DetailBlogPostView(BlogPostMixin,DetailView):
    template_name = 'HomeFeed/detail_blog.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = blog_post = self.get_object()
        blog_post.save()
        if blog_post.author in request.user.blocked_users.all():
            messages.warning(request, 'You cannot view post of ideas authors that you have blocked.', extra_tags='blockedposts')
            return redirect('HomeFeed:main')
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['blog_post'] = self.object
        context['account'] = Account.objects.all()

        if self.object.interest_set.exists():
            context["interest_pk"] = self.object.interest_set.first().pk
        
        return context
```

Comment: Hi, so basically i will have 2 functions in my class? or do i replace get context data with get and just shift all my code into get?

Comment: by adding your code into my existing code, it seems that the block system works but the rest of my other code doesnt as now I get a reverse match error for my other context

Comment: it's must be context["interest_pk" ] = self.object.interest_set.first().pk